# Perplexed as what caused my temporary issue, any idea?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

My PC did something weird yesterday.

When I tried to start it, this is what happened:

- The screen had lines as if broken and it was stuck on AsRock start screen
- Turned it off, then no beep on reboot, just blank
- Kept trying to turn it off and on, but blank screen, no start beep, and little LED light not flashing as usual, just blank

So I tried this:

- Disconnected power supply
- Connected and old power supply
- Tried to start the PC, didn't start
- Reconnected original power supply
- Then PC worked again and now using it to type this!.....

What could have been the issue?

Comment: The PC went into a BAD STATE (maybe some Electrical or Electronic Issue in Capacitor or CMOS) & It wanted a "Power Off" to recover. Disconnecting (+ Connecting) will eliminate the Power Issue. Nothing to worry about if that never occurs again.

Comment: Thanks, yes, now it's running fine, I was starting to look at motherboards and CPUs, relieved I don't need a new PC!

Answer (score 0):

Many times an intermittent issue like this can be an indication some component in your computer may be going bad or suffering a connectivity issue. If it is randomly or increasingly recurring and presumably you have already ruled out the power supply as a potential problem, I'd humbly advise you disconnect unnecessary peripheries to see if start up is still possible. If it is not, you may then need to additionally troubleshoot other internal components as you have the power supply, including memory modules, etc. Thereafter, reintroducing each of your disconnected components, one by one, back onto the mobo and ensuring power up after each sequential addition, should enable you to see which one is the potential culprit hanging up your system. It may be simply the act of re-seating your components could restore your PC's performance. Best to you.